# How to amend policy associated with Azure APIM APIs or operations with additional policy in automated way

Tags: xml, azure-api-management, xmlstarlet, azure-rest-api

I am trying to have an automated way to amend or apply additional policy on APIs or operations scope of Azure APIM and in my script i am able to read a variable $inbound or $outbound or $backend or $onerror as per user inputs. Now i am trying to apply this newly given policy to the API or Operations, where some global policies/ existing policies already applied. How to add or amend these newly adding policies  to the right session of the API or operations, without duplication them if the policy is already existing?

```
for f in $policy_ ; do
  if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_name) == "ipfilter" ]]; then
    echo " given policy name is ipfilter "

    if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_scope) == "api" ]]; then
      echo "decided the scope of Ipfilter policy as api "
    fi

    if [[ "$(eval echo \$${f}_apiname)" ]]; then
       echo "export the policy for the api $(eval echo \$${f}_apiname)"
       curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xx-rg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxx-apim/apis/myapi/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01" > effectivepolicy.xml
    fi

    if [ -z "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)" ]; then
        echo 'the inbound session is not present'
    fi
    if [[ "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)" ]]; then
      echo 'the inbound session is present and append the policy settings to inbound'
      inbound=$(printf "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)")
       echo "$inbound"
       Add the $inbound to the inbound session of policy.xml if its not existing and apply back 
    fi
```

For example here $inbound variable value is

```
<ip-filter action="allow">
 <address-range from="xxxxx" to="yyy" />
</ip-filter>
```

Below is the extracted effective policy sample from the api scope and need to amend and apply the same api with above newly added policy without duplication.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
            <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
            <cors xxxxxxxxxx="true">
            ****************************
            ****************************
            ****************************
            </cors>
            <!--base: End Global scope-->
    </inbound>
    <backend>
            <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
             ****************************
             ****************************
             ****************************
            <!--base: End Global scope-->
    </backend>
    <outbound>
            <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
            ****************************
            ****************************
            ****************************
            ****************************
            <!--base: End Global scope-->
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
            <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
            ****************************
            ****************************
            ****************************
            <!--base: End Global scope-->
    </on-error>
```

**Output of the custom policy file after trying the @khtesam Afrin Tried solution**

[parser](https://github.com/mrbaseman/parse_yaml) script tried.

input of policy file in yaml

---

```
- name: ipfilter
  scope: api
  apiname: xxxxx
  inboundsession: |
                <ip-filter action="allow">
                    <address-range from="xxxxx" to="yyyy" />
                </ip-filter>
  outboundsession: |
                <ip-filter action="allow">
                    <address-range from="xxxxx" to="vvvv" />
                </ip-filter>
```

policy Script Tried

---

```
source parse_yaml.sh
eval $(parse_yaml input.yaml policy)
echo ".............Eval Result..............................."
for f in $policy_ ; do eval echo \$f \$${f}_ ; done
echo "............Eval Result................................"

for f in $policy_ ; do
  if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_name) == "ipfilter" ]]; then
    echo " given policy name is ipfilter "

    if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_scope) == "api" ]]; then
      echo "decided the scope of Ipfilter policy as api "
    fi

    if [[ "$(eval echo \$${f}_apiname)" ]]; then
       echo "export the policy for the api $(eval echo \$${f}_apiname)"
       curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" "https://management.azure.com/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/ssssssss/apis/xxxxxxxxx/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01" > policy.xml
    fi

    if [ -z "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)" ]; then
        echo 'the inbound session is not present'
    fi
    if [[ "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)" ]]; then
      echo 'the inbound session is present and append the policy settings to inbound'
      inboundPolicy=$(printf "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)")
      echo "$inboundPolicy"
      if grep -qF "$inboundPolicy" policy.xml; then
        echo "Policy already exists in the inbound session."
      else
        # Insert the new policy into the existing policy XML
        echo "updating existing policy with new policy content"
        awk -v policy="$inboundPolicy" '/<\/inbound>/ && !p {print policy; p=1} 1' policy.xml > temp.xml
        mv temp.xml policy.xml
      fi
    fi
```

The parser script output for the variable `inboundPolicy`

---

```
<ip-filter action="allow">
 <address-range from="xxxxx" to="yyy" />
</ip-filter>
```

OutPut Of the Script

---

```
.............Eval Result...............................
policy1 policy1_name policy1_scope policy1_apiname policy1_inboundsession policy1_outboundsession
............Eval Result................................
 given policy name is ipfilter
decided the scope of Ipfilter policy as api
export the policy for the api xxxxxxx
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
the inbound session is present and append the below policy settings to inbound
<ip-filter action="allow">
 <address-range from="xxxxx" to="yyyyyyy" />
 </ip-filter>
updating existing policy with new policy content
the outbound session is present
the backend session is not present
```

Output of the custom policy file

---

```
<policies>^M
        <inbound>^M
                <!--base: Begin Global scope-->^M
                <cors axxxxxxx="true">^M
                        <xxxxxxx>^M
                                <origin>aaaaaaaaaaa</origin>^M
                                <origin>bbbbbbbbbbb</origin>^M
                                <origin>cccccccccccc</origin>^M
                        </xxxxxxx>^M
                </cors>^M
                <!--base: End Global scope-->^M
<ip-filter action="allow">
 <address-range from="xxxx" to="yyyy" />
 </ip-filter>
        </inbound>^M
        <backend>^M
                <!--base: Begin Global scope-->^M
                <forward-request />^M
                <!--base: End Global scope-->^M
```

Comment: why not declaring having the whole policy everytime ?then you just need to update the policy file and redeploy

Comment: We are trying to use this part of user input in yaml template, where the users can input the required policy settings only and as automation engineers we are trying to apply them in the given api or operations.

Comment: what is the value of `$policy_` you are passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the below script to check for duplication of the policy in effective policy before adding it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set variables
accessToken="eyJ0eXAi******qaoJinw"
subscriptionId="{subscriptionId}"
resourceGroupName="{resourceGroupName}"
apimServiceName="{apimServiceName}"
apiName="echo-api"
inboundPolicy='<set-header name="Test" exists-action="override">
            <value>Hi, Ikhtesam</value>
        </set-header>'

# Fetch existing effective policy XML
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" \
     "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$apimServiceName/apis/$apiName/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01" \
     > policy.xml

if grep -qF "$inboundPolicy" policy.xml; then
    echo "Policy already exists in the inbound session."
else
    # Insert the new policy into the existing policy XML
    awk -v policy="$inboundPolicy" '/<\/inbound>/ && !p {print policy; p=1} 1' policy.xml > temp.xml
    mv temp.xml policy.xml

    # Update the API's policy with the modified XML
    curl -X PUT \
  "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$apimServiceName/apis/$apiName/policies/policy?api-version=2022-08-01" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" \
  -d '{
    "properties": {
      "format": "xml",
      "value": "'"$(sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's/"/\\"/g' policy.xml)"'"
    }
  }'
    echo "Policy added to the inbound session."
fi
```

By executing this script, I am able to add the `set-header` policy successfully.

[image]

When I ran my script for `set-header` policy again, I got below output.

[image]

**Script for taking the inputs from yaml file.**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set variables
accessToken="eyJ0*****yXG6craOOQG3g"
subscriptionId="b823f"
resourceGroupName="RG_Name"
apimServiceName="Service_Name"
apiName="echo-api"

source parse_yaml.sh
eval $(parse_yaml input.yaml policy)
echo ".............Eval Result..............................."
for f in $policy_ ; do eval echo \$f \$${f}_ ; done
echo "............Eval Result................................"

for f in $policy_ ; do
  if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_name) == "setheader" ]]; then
    echo " given policy name is setheader "

    if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_scope) == "api" ]]; then
      echo "decided the scope of setheader policy as api "
    fi

    if [[ "$(eval echo \$${f}_apiname)" ]]; then
       echo "export the policy for the api $(eval echo \$${f}_apiname)"
       curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$apimServiceName/apis/$apiName/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01" > policy.xml
    fi

    if [ -z "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)" ]; then
        echo 'the inbound session is not present'
    fi
    if [[ "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)" ]]; then
      echo 'the inbound session is present and append the policy settings to inbound'
      inboundPolicy=$(printf "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession)")
      echo "$inboundPolicy"
      if grep -qF "$inboundPolicy" policy.xml; then
        echo "Policy already exists in the inbound session."
      else
        # Insert the new policy into the existing policy XML
        awk -v policy="$inboundPolicy" '/<\/inbound>/ && !p {print policy; p=1} 1' policy.xml > temp.xml
        mv temp.xml policy.xml

        # Update the API's policy with the modified XML
        curl -X PUT \
        "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$apimServiceName/apis/$apiName/policies/policy?api-version=2022-08-01" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" \
        -d '{
            "properties": {
                "format": "xml",
                "value": "'"$(sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's/"/\\"/g' policy.xml)"'"
            }
        }'
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

**Output**-

[image]

In this way, you can add the policy without duplication.

Comment: Great idea.. I tried above solution to create a custom policy file , but didn't try to apply it back, as the generated xml file structure is not the same way as the exported effective policy file. The line which is added the policy to the wrong indentation and all the line has added with some characters like "^M". will this impact the policy configuration ?  Adding the custom policy file generated to the question part.

Comment: @Vowneee here I am passing a policy in a variable and then amending it to the effective policy. In my case, it is correctly amended. To get the indentation correct, you need to pass the format is XML in the request body while making the put call. Are you using my script or modified anything in my script?

Comment: Here in my script, the policy I am getting as a variable output from the yaml parser script and the the variables output structure is in expected xml format itself. And I have added your suggested solution to replace the content to the exported api script. Adding my script sample to the edited part of the question

Comment: @Vowneee Can you try my script only?

Comment: I can make a try with your script, but my end goal is to read the policy from users input yaml file and apply them to the given api under scope.

Comment: Sure, I will try to merge your script with mine and will provide you the updated script

Comment: Please help me with the value you are passing for $policy_ variable in your script

Comment: Modified the question with the policy input and generated output.

Comment: @Vowneee Can you please share your code for `parse_yaml.sh`

Comment: This is the same script which used from here. https://github.com/mrbaseman/parse_yaml

Comment: @Vowneee added the updated script in my answer, please check

Comment: WOW.. that worked as expected when we applied the policy to the api. Only one challenge now I am facing is when I want to reapply the same policy with some value changes alone, eg:  only change the value of "from=" and "to=" values in the ipfilter policy in requirement basis. Right now, once the policy is applied, we cant change the value inside the policy as its checking for the existence of the policy and not the string values provided in them.

Comment: Did you retry the script in your scenario? I guess it will not update the api policy if we reapply with policy value change in them. Seems first time apply will work and update in the policy value will not work as  its not comparing entire string value

Comment: @Vowneee Yes I tried it. It will only amend the policy from yaml file by checking the duplication. I believe this was your requirement. It is not checking the entire string value in XML. If you will try to change some value in the given policy like from and to value then it will not check them

Comment: oh..ok.. I understood. so this can be used at first time and re-update not possible.  might be we may need to check other possible options for grep command here

Comment: @Vowneee Or else you can open a new question for your requirement, community will help you